# Is there a way to disable PIN lock of my device?

Tags: lock-screen, unlocking

Recently I gave my HTC 8X to my kid to play with and I forgot to switch to Kids corner for him

So, I actually managed to stop him from setting new PIN lock of lockscreen (I am not using any password protection by default) and it make me wondering:

If I accidentally set up new lock password and manage to forget it, is there a way how to unlock such device? I obviously have it connected with my Microsoft account

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's not possible. From the [WP8 Lock Screen FAQ](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-gb/how-to/wp8/settings-and-personalization/lock-screen-faq):

> If you just aren't able to come up with the right password, you'll need to reset your phone to factory settings.

Comment: Oh, shoot! I feel like I am glad now that I stopped my kid at right moment :)